# How to plot a common colorbar for mutiple raster plots in a single image in R?

Tags: raster, r

I am plotting a spatial map of monthly temperature. I need to keep a common scale for all the months. How to do this in R?

I have included my code below with the generated map. How can I reduce the additional space shown by blue arrows?

```
library(raster)

png(
  "Image.png",
  width     = 12,
  height    = 10,
  units     = "in",
  res       = 1200,
  point     = 10
)
 par(mar=c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), mfrow=c(3,4), oma = c(4, 4, 2, 2))

for (i in 1:12){

  month_col = i+2 #Since months start from 3 column  
  r = rasterFromXYZ(testing[,c(2,1,month_col)])
  plot(r)

}

dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Use the zlim argument to plot, give it the min, max values, use asp = "" to avoid the aspect ratio fudging

Comment: but how to display a common color bar instead at a specific location.

Comment: There are not any packages called "gplot", maybe your mean had been "gplots".

Answer (score 1):

I see you make a for loop to print each time, if you do this, each time it will print a scale; you may set it to false and at the end place it;

For a job like the one you want to do i used

```
library(gplot)
```

which, like the "raster" package is also created by R: Hijmans
it facets like ggplot2, prints a single scalebar and you may also give spatialpolygonsdataframes to it.

For reducing space, pass a `bbox()` or `extent()` argument to your plot function, this fits the plotting region to your spatial data